# Extract text from a Text Box of a Word document using Office JS Api

Tags: javascript, ms-word, office-js

I am having some TextBoxes ( Shape > Text Box) inside a word document. The document is a CV template which includes a lot of them. I would like to select all Textboxes of the document, extract text, remove the text boxes and inject the extracted text. I have tried

```
 const range =  context.document.getSelection();
 range.load("text");
```

and then sync the context so that I can get the text.

Comment: Please provide more of your code and explain what goes wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally took the following workaround. It is and fast and works nicely in both Windows & macOS

1. Get OOXML of the document's body
2. Parse OOXL.value &  Generate an xmlDocument (xmlDoc)
3. Detect existing Textboxes & Shapes that contain text:  getElementsByTagName("wps:wsp")
4. Extract text from (3)
5. Generate a simple xml  TextElement with text extracted
6. Replace (3) with (5)
7. Serialize to xmlString  the updated xmlDoc and get the updated OOXML.value
8. Insert updated OOXML.value to document replacing the existing one

   Word.run(function (context) {

   ```
        //Select document body and extract OOXML 
        const body = context.document.body;
        const ooxml = body.getOoxml();

        return context.sync().then(function () {

            //Initialize DOM Parser
            const parser = new DOMParser();
            const xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(ooxml.value, "text/xml");

            //Get all runs
            const rows = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("w:r");
            for (let j = 0; j < rows.length; j++) {
                const row = rows[j];
                const rowHasTextBox = row.getElementsByTagName("wps:txbx").length > 0;
                //If no textbox, shape, wordart exists skip current run
                if (!rowHasTextBox) continue;

                //Select textbox, shape, wordart and get paragraphs
                const textboxContainer = row.getElementsByTagName("wps:txbx")[0];
                const paragraphs = textboxContainer.getElementsByTagName("w:p");

                // Create a new run which will replace the existing run
                const newRow = xmlDoc.createElement("w:r");
                const breakLine = xmlDoc.createElement("w:br");
                //Append breakline and "{{"
                newRow.appendChild(breakLine);
                newRow.appendChild(startRow);

                for (let p = 0; p < paragraphs.length; p++) {
                    //Check whether paragrapj has text
                    const paragraphHasText = paragraphs[p].getElementsByTagName("w:t").length > 0;
                    if (!paragraphHasText) continue;
                    //Extract text
                    let textExtracted = "";
                    const textBoxTexts = paragraphs[p].getElementsByTagName("w:t");
                    for (let k = 0; k < textBoxTexts.length; k++) {
                        const textBoxText = textBoxTexts[k].innerHTML;
                        textExtracted = textExtracted + textBoxText;
                        textExtracted = textExtracted + " ";
                    }
                     // Create a temp run which will hold the etxtracted text
                    const tempRow = xmlDoc.createElement("w:r");
                    const newText = xmlDoc.createElement('w:t');
                    newText.setAttribute("xml:space", "preserve");
                    newText.innerHTML = textExtracted;
                    textExtracted = "";
                    tempRow.appendChild(newText);
                    newRow.appendChild(tempRow);
                    const breakLine = xmlDoc.createElement("w:br");
                    newRow.appendChild(breakLine);
                }


                //Replace existing run with the new one
                row.replaceWith(newRow);
            }
            //Serialize dom , clear body and replace OOXML
            const serializedXML = new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(xmlDoc.documentElement);
            body.clear();
            return context.sync().then(function () {
                body.insertOoxml(serializedXML, Word.InsertLocation.replace);
                console.log('done');
            });
        });
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.log('Error: ', error);
        resolve(false);
    });
   ```

Comment: Any way you can post full code? This unfortunately does not work